# Gremlin query to assign single property to all connected components

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I need to write query which does following steps:

1. Takes selected vertexes ids and goes through all connected components with SinglePath.
2. Each of initial and connected vertex may have gl_id property assigned. If it is already assigned I want to take one property value (there might be different gl_id values for different vertexes) and assign it to all components connected to initial vertex.
3. If none of connected component has gl_id property then assign initial name as gl_id.
4. Update properties in Neptune database

I have following code

```
update_vertices = g.V(v_id) \
    .as_('f') \
    .emit().repeat(both('seen', 'noticed').simplePath()).dedup().as_('cc')\
    .property(single, "gl_id", select('f').values('name')).iterate()
```

where v_id can be lots of vertex_ids e.g. 10000k

Current code will always update gl_id property based on initial v_id, but I want to do it only if there is no gl_id assigned in any connected component. Otherwise I want to take existing value and pass it to all connected components.

In the latter part I can use `coalesce()` to put points 2 and 3 into single property but I do not know how to replicate property value from single vertex to whole group of vertexes.

Tried already with SideEffect(), project(), group().by().by()

Comment: I think you need two passes through each connected component, one to detect any g_id value and the other to distribute the now known g_id value over the connected component. Did you try that too?